# Selecting columns based on conditions imposed on the contents

Tags: python, pandas

How would you select columns and column names based on conditions like isna() or std devs? If I had a dataframe like

```
    A    B    C    D
0   1    2    3    4
1   5   NaN   3    2 
2   9    8    7    6
3   9   NaN   3    3
```

and wanted it to return something like `['A', 'B']` where `'A'` is is beyond a certain standard deviation and `'B'` is beyond a certain NaN threshold (i.e. >= 50% empty), what would be an efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your std cut point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
std_thresh = 3
nan_thresh = 0.5
summary = df.describe()
flags = (summary.loc['std'].ge(std_thresh) | 
         summary.loc['count'].le(nan_thresh*len(df)))

df[df.columns[flags]]
```

Comment: @WeNYoBen I assume it's something OP wants to put there.

Comment: Ah ok fair enough :-)